# How to write a pd.dataframe method?

Tags: python, pandas

```
def f(df):
    # do sth on pd.df
    return new_df
```

Any way could let me use `df.f()` instead of using `f(df)` to execute `f()` on `df`?

Comment: I obviously marked this a dup... but if I agree with @PaulH.  If you don't need to, then don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't go to the place where you subclass the DataFrame. There be dragons.

Instead, write your function as you have and then do:

`df = df.pipe(your_fxn)`

Comment: You got a chuckle out of me with the "dragons" comment.

Comment: One for the dragons